# I want to see data in gridview by using sqlite (data) but my app become too slow

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am developing an application. In this I am using the sqlite database.
And I want to show data in gridview and data is above 15k that why my app become very slow.Screen going to black for a second after that data is showing.

When data is below 5k then its working fine but when data is across 10k then app become too slow.

Showing all data but screen blink a second.

Comment: why you are not using pagination , get some data first and on request keep on getting more data from db, in this way your app will also not become slow

Comment: @Danialclarc bcoz its not required to showing in pagination.

Comment: do not show it to user but do it on scroll .@Afroz Ahmad

Comment: @Danialclarc I will try this one.

Answer (score 1):

GridView is so Old same ListView also old. Use **RecyclerView**.

**What is the problem?**

GridView or ListView are hold or load full list of data where as `RecyclerView` only hold the data that are currently showing in Screen mean Visible screen. [you can hold means processing or somethings similar that].

So what you have to do?

1. If you want to show data as like Grid you can use `GridLayoutManager` with `RecyclerView`
2. You can use pagination with `recyclerView` . And good news is google has own Pagination library for android. You can get details [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging).
3. Add your http call in background thread and show data in UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to load datas in an `AsyncTask` in background and then display these datas when there are completely load.

While the datas are loading, your screen show a loading logo or a progress bar, and then, display your datas in your gridview.

Somtehing like this :

```
new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>(){
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                //Display your loader
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                //Load your datas
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                //Close your loader
                //Display your datas
            }
        }.execute(null,null,null);
```

By this way, the UI Thread won't be blocked and the display still be smooth.